# SQL: Differences between times and counting the frequency

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data ordered by events, ID and then start_time:

```
EVENT  ID   START_TIME  END_TIME
1      101     1:00      2:00
1      101     3:00      3:30
1      102     1:00      4:00
1      102     5:00      6:00
2      103     10:00     11:00
2      103     12:00     13:00
2      103     13:30     14:00
2      103     14:30     15:00
```

And I want to end up with the following:

```
Difference_hour Frequency
1                  3
0,5                2
```

I would like to obtain a query that is looking at the difference between the END_TIME of an ID and the START_TIME of the same ID within the same EVENT (to mention specifically, i am not interested in the difference between the START_TIME and END_TIME of the same row).

Example: in event 1 we have to ID's 101, and I would like to have the difference between the first END_TIME (2:00) and the following START_TIME on the second row 3:00). The difference is 1 hour. If we do this similar for ID 102, we end up with another difference of 1 hour.

In the end, I would like to count the frequency of each of the differences, which can be seen in the second table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select diff_hour, count(*)
from
  (
  select (next_start - end_time)*86400 as diff_hour
  from
    (
    select end_time, lead(start_time) over (partition by event, id order by start_time) next_start
    from MyTable
    ) x1
  where next_start is not null
  ) x2
group by diff_hour
```

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the quick reply! It seems to work well, I just have a different time that  includes the date, and I expect that because of that it doesnt show the correct times. The times including the date is presented in the following way: <2016-12-31 21:09:55>. How does the query look with this date? 

Example: when END_TIME <2016-12-31 21:09:55>  and START_TIME <2016-12-31 21:13:02> Then I would like to have the difference in hours, which is 0.0519444444 hours. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Younes Oracle doesn't have a "time" type, it just uses dates. To display in HH:MM, you'll need to turn it into text.

Comment: Hi John, i got it to work, thanks again for your quick help, much appreciated!